# persistentIdentifier not saved for Siri Shortcuts using NSUserActivity

Tags: sirishortcuts

I'm adding Siri Shortcuts to my app using INUIAddVoiceShortcutViewController and things are working fine, except when I try to delete a shortcut using NSUserActivity.deleteSavedUserActivities(withPersistentIdentifiers:)

I verified the persistentIdentifier is not being saved for the NSUserActivity. Below is the code that I used to create the NSUserActivity:

```
func createUserActivityForShortcut(workoutName: String, timerID: String) -> NSUserActivity? {  

    let userActivity = NSUserActivity(activityType: "com.fourthframe.intervals.start-timer")  
    userActivity.isEligibleForSearch = true  

    userActivity.isEligibleForPrediction = true  
    userActivity.suggestedInvocationPhrase = "Start \(workoutName)"  

    userActivity.title = "Start \(workoutName)"  
    userActivity.userInfo = ["timerID": timerID]  
    userActivity.persistentIdentifier = timerID  
    userActivity.needsSave = true  
    userActivity.requiredUserInfoKeys = ["timerID"]  
    userActivity.becomeCurrent()  

    return userActivity  

}
```

Is this a known issue or did I do something wrong?
Thanks,
Jeff

Comment: Also facing this same issue.  The persistentIdentifier is not being saved.

Comment: Radar filed if you want to dupe: rdar://45809778